# Тень для кнопки. Css

Tags: css, button

Есть кнопка, нужно сделать для нее тень как на картинке. Пытался создать ещё один блок `div`, наклонить его, закрасить что бы он был как тень но не вышло, подскажите.

```css
input#submit {
 width: 312px;
 height: 40px;
 background: #635960;
 color: #fffecd;
 font-family: 'Montserrat';
 font-size: 21px;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="Submit"  id="submit" value="Submit">
```

[image: Сама тень]

Comment: на градиент похоже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чуток похоже..

> но у меня не понятка почему пришлось body минусовать `z-index`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -100;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: rgb(99, 89, 96);
  color: lightgreen;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

button:after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 0;
  left: 83px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(200, 200, 200, .3), rgba(240, 240, 240, .2), rgba(200, 200, 200, 0));
  transform: skew(28deg);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<button>submit</button>
```